# update wp_set_post_terms not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Actually I am using wp job manager plugin. The plugin has only one custom taxonomy
Here is the code to register taxonomy in plugin

```
register_taxonomy( "job_listing_type",
            array( "job_listing" ),
            array(
                'hierarchical'          => true,
                'label'                 => $plural,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'              => $plural,
                    'singular_name'     => $singular,
                    'search_items'      => sprintf( __( 'Search %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $plural ),
                    'all_items'         => sprintf( __( 'All %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $plural ),
                    'parent_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $singular ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s:', 'wp-job-manager' ), $singular ),
                    'edit_item'         => sprintf( __( 'Edit %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $singular ),
                    'update_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Update %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $singular ),
                    'add_new_item'      => sprintf( __( 'Add New %s', 'wp-job-manager' ), $singular ),
                    'new_item_name'     => sprintf( __( 'New %s Name', 'wp-job-manager' ),  $singular )
                ),
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'query_var'             => true,
                'capabilities'          => array(
                    'manage_terms'      => $admin_capability,
                    'edit_terms'        => $admin_capability,
                    'delete_terms'      => $admin_capability,
                    'assign_terms'      => $admin_capability,
                ),
               'rewrite'                => $rewrite,
            )
        );
```

Then I added Three more taxonomies using

```
function skw_build_taxonomies() {



    //Sports
     $brand_args = array(
     'label' => 'Sports',
     'hierarchical' => true,
     'query_var' => true,
     'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sport-cat')
     );
     register_taxonomy( 'sport-cat', 'job_listing', $brand_args );

      //Arts
     $brand_args1 = array(
     'label' => 'Arts & Music',
     'hierarchical' => true,
     'query_var' => true,
     'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'art-cat')
     );
     register_taxonomy( 'art-cat', 'job_listing', $brand_args1 );

     //Academic & Tech
     $brand_args2 = array(
     'label' => 'Academic & Tech',
     'hierarchical' => true,
     'query_var' => true,
     'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'academic-cat')
     );
     register_taxonomy( 'academic-cat', 'job_listing', $brand_args2 );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'skw_build_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Instead of this code I also used the plugin's code by changing taxonomy name and slug.
Now after inserting post, this code sets taxonomy successfully.
But when I want to update the post by using a custom form at front end, it adds the term related to taxonomy job_listing_type to all the four taxonomies and sets it. and sets the other three taxonomy terms correctly.
Here is my code to set the terms.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_job_academic[]" value="<?php echo $term->id; ?>" <?php if(in_array($term->slug,$slug)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $term->name ?></span>//sample html in the form
```

and here is php code to set the terms

```
wp_set_post_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_type'], 'job_listing_type' );
            wp_set_post_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_arts'], 'art-cat' );
            wp_set_post_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_academic'], 'academic-cat' );
            wp_set_post_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_sports'], 'sport-cat' );
```

I also tested this but same result

```
wp_set_object_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_type'], 'job_listing_type', false );
            wp_set_object_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_arts'], 'art-cat', false );
            wp_set_object_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_academic'], 'academic-cat', false );
            wp_set_object_terms( $postid, $_POST['_job_sports'], 'sport-cat', false );
```

for example
I have four taxonomies named x1, x2, x3, x4

```
x1 has terms a, b, c, d
x2 has terms e, f, g, h
x3 has terms i, j, k, l
x4 has terms m, n, o, p
```

at front end, these terms are shown with checkboxes. So suppose I have checked a, e, i, m  terms. So all of these should be set for that post. Bet wp_set_post_terms adds the term of X1 to all other taxonomies. Here is the final result

```
x1 has terms a, b, c, d, d
x2 has terms e, f, g, h, d
x3 has terms i, j, k, l, d
x4 has terms m, n, o, p, d
```

Comment: Please ask your question specifically. I think I can parse your prose to figure out what is happening, and what you want to happen, but I'm not sure. (And people on SO don't want to struggle to understand questions.) You might also consider asking this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, I have added an example at the end of the question to explain my question. May be I can explain it to you by this way. also can you send me your email so that I can send you the exact code with more detail.